# Different header for each chapter in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I'm trying to place the chapter titles for a document in the page headers. I've set the header content to the title of the first chapter, but every page has the same header, so the first chapter's title shows up on every page. How can I define chapters in my document and display different headers for each?

Comment: How exactly did you add the Chapter 1 title to the Header?